# Writing Null Values to a Text File from Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, null, android-sqlite

Having difficulties with writing an SQLite database into a text file.

The app works by importing a csv file into a local database. That database is used to collect data on the device and then the user exports the data back into a csv file to be collected back into a main Access database.

If the csv file is imported and then immediately exported it works perfectly. However, as soon as new entries are made into the database the export creates an empty txt file.

I believe that the issue is blank values in the database are saved as *Null* values and there's an issue with them being written to a text file. I'm just not sure whether the correct response would be to change the collection so that it will write a blank entry instead of a *Null* value or if there's a way to write *Null* as a blank value into the csv file.

For reference, here's my export code.

```
try {
    Log.d("try", "initiated");
    cursor = db.query("PROD",
            new String[]{"_id", "PUMPER_NO", "WELL_ID", "TANK1_INV", "TANK2_INV", "TANK3_INV", "PROB1", "PROB2", "WATER_RMVD", "OSALE1_IN", "OSALE1_DATE", "OSALE1_TK", "OSALE1_BBL",
                    "OSALE2_IN", "OSALE2_DATE", "OSALE2_TK", "OSALE2_BBL", "GAGED_FLUID", /*"DIFF",*/ "MCFD", "MCF_CUM", "TUBING", "CASING", "LINE", "CYCLES", "CYC_TIME", "CYC_DAYS", "DAYS_OFF",
                    "HRS_PUMPED", "COMMENTS", "MTRIX", "DTF", "TMF", "XTRA1", "XTRA2"},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    int rowcount = 0;
    int colcount = 0;

    Log.d("FileWriter", "initiated");
    File saveFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Wellpro/exportprod.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(saveFile, false);

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    rowcount = cursor.getCount();
    colcount = cursor.getColumnCount();
    Log.d("Looping", "initiated");
    if (rowcount > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < colcount; i++) {
            if (i != colcount - 1) {
                bw.write(cursor.getColumnName(i) + ",");
            } else {
                bw.write(cursor.getColumnName(i));
            }
        }
        bw.newLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < colcount; j++) {
                if (j != colcount - 1) {
                    bw.write(cursor.getString(j) + ",");
                } else {
                    bw.write(cursor.getString(j));
                }
            }
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.flush();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Exported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    if (db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

And here are two entries. The one with no *Null* values is from the original CSV file and the second entry is the one created within the program. Prior to the second entry being created the export works fine.

```
"8" "8" "1255"  "ALESI-OVINGTON #2" "79.0"  "0.0"   "0.0"   ";" ";" "0.0"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "0.0"   "NULL"  "4.68"  "28.08" "0.0"   "0.0"   "60.0"  "0.0"   "0.0"   "0.0"   "0" "0.0"   "Not pumping"   "2.0"   "2016/09/26"    ""  "6" ""  "NULL"  "NULL"

"124"   "124"   "NULL"  "ALESI-OVINGTON #2" "81.0"  "0.0"   "0.0"   "NULL"  "NULL"  "0.0"   "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "2.0"   "10.0"  "10.47" "227.01"    "0.0"   "0.0"   "60.0"  "0.0"   "0.0"   "0.0"   "0" "0.0"   ""  "NULL"  "2016/10/15"    "NULL"  "NULL"  "NULL"  "1.0"   "1.0"
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The first line is the one that exports correctly though... I think that the issue is maybe that the code doesn't know how to write "NULL" to the text file?

What would be the easiest way to replace all the Null values with a "" though? I'm assuming just run a find and replace query?

Comment: Check for IFNULL() function in Sqlite . So that you can handle NULL Value to " " within single query.

Comment: The `catch` clause is superfluous, and suppresses all exceptions. Remove it.